# Writing javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am new to PHP, I just need to write a javascript code inside php file like we doing in jsp.

Below is the sample code where am trying to do that, Please help me out to embed my javascript code in php

**getencryp.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsencrypt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var b=getAccountbyEncrptInfo('xxx','yyyy')
function getAccountbyEncrptInfo(user,pass)
{
    var omegaKey = 'abc';
    var crypt = new JSEncrypt();
    crypt.setPublicKey(omegaKey);
    var creds = {
     username: user,
     password: pass
    };
    creds.username = crypt.encrypt(creds.username);
    creds.password = crypt.encrypt(creds.password);
    return JSON.stringify(creds);
}
</script>

<?php
echo Your encrypted username and password is $b;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code am just passing two values in java script **getAccountbyEncrptInfo('xxx','yyyy')** and just trying to print inside php body.

Comment: You do realize that Java and JavaScript have nothing to do with each other, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is  a variable in javascript and it's not a variable in PHP. So that you can't echo it in the PHP tag.
I think you should implement the function `getAccountbyEncrptInfo` in PHP code or binding the variable from javascript into the html tag instead of using echo in PHP. It should be something like:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsencrypt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var b=getAccountbyEncrptInfo('xxx','yyyy');
document.getElementById('encrypted').html(b);
function getAccountbyEncrptInfo(user,pass)
{
    var omegaKey = 'abc';
    var crypt = new JSEncrypt();
    crypt.setPublicKey(omegaKey);
    var creds = {
     username: user,
     password: pass
    };
    creds.username = crypt.encrypt(creds.username);
    creds.password = crypt.encrypt(creds.password);
    return JSON.stringify(creds);
}
</script>

<div id="encrypted"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this line after var `b` declaration

```
$('#answer').html(b);
```

and replace
echo Your encrypted username and password is `$b;`

this line with this line

Your encrypted username and password is `div id="answer"></div`

just make a blank div and set it`s id answer so js is set the value on it

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use PHP?

```
<script>
    var b = getAccountbyEncrptInfo('xxx','yyyy');
    document.getElementById('ex').append(" Your encrypted username and password is " + b)
</script>
```

However if you wanted to append it inside the `<?php ?>` tags to further process your data, you might want to consider using an AJAX request.